# Jumptron background image disappears when I scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap jumptron and a background image. As I scroll down the background image disappears leaving the jumptron div class only showing the heading. How can it be fix so when I scroll down the image doesn't desappear. The other content works proper, The following files provide more detail. The following files are in a Rails 5 app.

index.html.erb

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Organize and Mobilize</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>We need you to take action</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    <br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Page Content</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    <h2>Page Content</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
    <h2>Page Content</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.

  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Page Content</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
    Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
    dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
    Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><p>The End.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

bootstrap_and_overrides.css

```css
/*
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap

  Static version of css will use Glyphicons sprites by default
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites
*/
body { padding-top: 50px; }

.bg {
  background: url('protest.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px; /*same height as jumbotron */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 350px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
  background:transparent;
}
```

and  cable.js

```js
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the rails generate channel command.
//
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);

var jumboHeight = $('.jumbotron').outerHeight();
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.bg').css('height', (jumboHeight-scrolled) + 'px');
}

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    parallax();
});
```

[image]

This is the image before I scroll the page:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put an image as the background of the jumbotron, that's not what it's for.

Instead, make the jumbotron background color transparent, then add the background image to the div outside of the container.

ie. in HAML

```
#YourDivToApplyBackground
    .container
        .row
            .col-md-12
                .jumbotron
                    %h1 Your Page Title
```

This is how your code should look for bootstrap.

Comment: add the image to which div?

Comment: This is not required, if the snippet of code worked in the link you sent me, the problem has to originate from the 'app build' itself. I can't be the html, css, or js. I think it has to do with rails. In the link you sent me, everything was working great. So now think about the things that have changed??? What are those?? You are running this by using rails correct??